# Django does not download file from query

Tags: django, file, download

I have a Django app where I need to allow a user to download a log file generated from a query.
I have created a view for the download, and I generate the file - but once the client presses the button (called with ajax), nothing gets downloaded.

My View is as follows:

```
def download_rollback(request):
    serial = request.POST.get('serial')
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}.csv"'.format(serial)

    writer =  csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['timestamp','serial','log'])
    
    queryset = ConfigLog.objects.filter(ser_no=serial).filter(log__contains='ROLLBACK')
    for obj in queryset:
        writer.writerow([obj.timestamp, obj.ser_no, obj.log])

    return response
```

and I have the following urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('beaconing/download_rollback/', views.download_rollback,name='download_rollback'),
    ...
]
```

I have followed various tutorials to try this - they all pointed to something like the above, but none works.

Here is my ajax request:

```js
function Download(ser_no){
  console.log('AJAX');
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{% url "beacon_server:download_rollback" %}', 
                data: {
                            serial: ser_no,
                            type: "Download",
                  csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                  action: 'post'
                },
                success: function (json) {
   
                    },
                    error: function (xhr,errmsg,err) {

                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note is that, it should be a `get` reqquest not `post`,
So change your python function accordingly.
eg: `serial = request.POST.get('serial')` to `serial = request.GET.get('serial')`

Then, instead of sending request through ajax, Try this way

```
function Download(ser_no){
    location.href = '/beaconing/download_rollback/?serial='+ser_no
}
```

Comment: You are a star. Thanks

Comment: You're always welcome.